# Suggestions and references for a modern-looking and clean UI?

Tags: gui-design, web-app, input-fields

I'm working on the UI of a single-page application that allows users to manage (add, edit and remove entries) information about their products.

The interface must be capable of presenting hundreds of product forms at once, each one containing at least 15 editable data inputs with info of the product.

The thing here is that I need something clean and that looks good for web. Definitely something more like a "editable Facebook wall" then a straight excel sheet/SQL management program interface.

To illustrate, here's my first attempt to it. I feel it looks ugly and "dated", more like a windows application...

[image]

Can you give insights on how to improve it and make it looks more modern and cleaner?

Also I can't find no example of website running an interface like this so I could just base me on it (which would help A LOT). Can you provide any example or template to help me with this?

Comment: The question seems to aim to a graphic design recommendation not necessarily an UX one.

Comment: Sometimes a "straight excel sheet" UI *is* the ideal solution. Not saying it is your case, but don't discount it outright. If you've used the web app Toggl, I think that's a great example of overthinking what is, essentially, a spreadsheet and would have been better presented as a simple spreadsheet.

Comment: As for this example, give us a use case. Would a user typically be editing *all* of these records in one sitting? Or just one or two?

Comment: Go to behance.net and dribble.com and search for "clean", you will find awesome latest design works by designers across the world for inspiration and references. Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into a few of these design guides.

**Googles Material Design:**

http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

**Bootstrap:**

http://getbootstrap.com/

Either one is going to give you 'clean' web ready out of the box.

Comment: These are fine suggestions for a broad page framework but don't really address the specifics of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks abit crowded because you are showing all the information on the same screen at the same time. the screen shot isn't clear but it looks like you could replace the sequence of the same fields with an add button.[image]

Try to think in terms of when the user will need to use which block of information, and show clear navigation on how the user can pull out screens that would show the information the user needs to perform their functons